# Root is unable to install python packages in aws

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running an EC2 instance in aws with ubuntu 18.04 image.
I'm unable to install python packages for root:

```
$ python3 -m pip install tornado
```

Works for user ubuntu, but:

```
$ sudo su
# python3 -m pip install tornado
Collecting tornado
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fef245955c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/tornado/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fef24595c88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/tornado/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fef24595fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/tornado/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fef24595198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/tornado/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fef24595f98>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/tornado/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tornado (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tornado
```

What can be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Compare `which python3` with  `sudo which python3`;  `python3 --version` with  `sudo python3 --version`

Comment: Same binary, same versions.